# Having trouble evaluating infix expressions

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a program that will take in an error free infix expression and evaluate it using two stacks. For most things it works pretty well, but an expression with parentheses crashes the program and an expression like 2 – 3 + 4 * 5 / 6 outputs 6.33 while the answer is 2.33. This is a homework assignment so any hints would be helpful.

```
import java.util.Stack;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class InfixEvaluation<T> extends Stack<T>{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public static boolean isNumber(String string) {
    try {
        Double.parseDouble(string);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

 public static boolean hasPrecedence(char num1, char num2) {
        if ((num1 == '+' || num1 == '-') && (num2 == '*' || num2 == '/'))
            return false;
        else
            return true;
 }

public static Double evaluateInfix(String expression) {
    double result = 0;
    StringTokenizer tokens = new StringTokenizer(expression, " ");
    Stack<Character> operatorStack = new Stack<Character>();
    Stack<Double> valueStack = new Stack<Double>();

    while(tokens.hasMoreTokens()) {
        String nextToken = tokens.nextToken();
        //System.out.println(nextToken);

        if(isNumber(nextToken)) 
            valueStack.push(Double.parseDouble(nextToken));
        if(nextToken.equals("^"))
            operatorStack.push(nextToken.charAt(0));
        if(nextToken.equals("("))
            operatorStack.push(nextToken.charAt(0));
        if(nextToken.equals("+") || nextToken.equals("-") || nextToken.equals("*") || nextToken.equals("/")) {
            while(!operatorStack.empty() && hasPrecedence(operatorStack.peek(),nextToken.charAt(0))) {
                Double operand1 = valueStack.pop();
                Double operand2 = valueStack.pop();
                Character operator = operatorStack.pop();

                if(operator.equals('+'))
                    result = operand1 + operand2;
                else if(operator.equals('^'))
                    result = Math.pow(operand2, operand1);
                else if(operator.equals('-'))
                    result = operand2 - operand1;
                else if(operator.equals('*'))
                    result = operand1 * operand2;
                else
                    result = operand2 / operand1;

                valueStack.push(result);    
            }
            operatorStack.push(nextToken.charAt(0));
        }
        if(nextToken.equals(")")) {
            while(!operatorStack.peek().equals("(")) {
                Double operand1 = valueStack.pop();
                Double operand2 = valueStack.pop();
                Character operator = operatorStack.pop();

                if(operator.equals('+'))
                    result = operand1 + operand2;
                else if(operator.equals('^'))
                    result = Math.pow(operand2, operand1);
                else if(operator.equals('-'))
                    result = operand2 - operand1;
                else if(operator.equals('*'))
                    result = operand1 * operand2;
                else
                    result = operand2 / operand1;

                valueStack.push(result);

            }
            operatorStack.pop();
        }
    }


    while(!operatorStack.empty()) {
        Double operand1 = valueStack.pop();
        Double operand2 = valueStack.pop();
        Character operator = operatorStack.pop();



        if(operator.equals('+'))
            result = operand1 + operand2;
        else if(operator.equals('^'))
            result = Math.pow(operand2, operand1);
        else if(operator.equals('-'))
            result = operand2 - operand1;
        else if(operator.equals('*'))
            result = operand1 * operand2;
        else
            result = operand2 / operand1;

        valueStack.push(result);
    }




    return valueStack.peek();
 }

}
```

When i put in parentheses this comes up:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.EmptyStackException
at java.util.Stack.peek(Stack.java:102)
at java.util.Stack.pop(Stack.java:84)
at InfixEvaluation.evaluateInfix(InfixEvaluation.java:42)
at EvaluatorDemo.main(EvaluatorDemo.java:7)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a `EmptyStackException`, this means you are trying to pop an element from your `Stack` but this one is empty. To avoid this you should surround all the `pop`calls with try catch:

```
try {
    operatorStack.pop();
    } catch (EmptyStackException e) {}
```